# Why is data fetched from API using react-hook provided inconsistently?

Tags: get, axios, react-hooks

I am trying to render some string of names using React-hook. The data is fetched from the '/api/getMoreCards' end point, which is defined in the controller file, and works fine.

The problem is that when I store the fetched data into 'data' of react-hook's useState object, it inconsistently gives access to the data. Let me be more specific:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
const regeneratorRuntime = require("regenerator-runtime");

const HS = () => {
  const getData = async() => {
    const data = await axios.get('/api/getMoreCards')
    console.log(data)
    setData(data)
}
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
    useEffect(()=>{
      getData()
    },[]);

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>List of Cards</h1>
        **<div>{data.data[0].name}</div>**
      </div>
    );
}
export default HS;
```

This file is exported into App.js.

In the above code, the `data.data[0].name` is sometimes rendered on the localhost correctly, but most of the times, it gives me the error of:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at HS (hsContainer.js:76)" on the console.

In this case, the console logging on line 7 does not appear in the console at all.

I have tried closing and reopening VScode, changing the file to 'jsx', declared the `data.data[0].name` as a constant, changing the order of getData and useState codes, all of which were still inconsistent.

Here are my webpack.config.js and package.json file for reference:

Webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              mimetype: 'image/png'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.js',
      '.jsx'
    ],
    alias: {
      'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom'
    }
  },
  devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        proxy: {
            '/api': 'http://localhost:3000',
            '/api/profile': 'http://localhost:3000',
        },
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: `./public/index.html`,
    }),
  ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Solo-Project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node ./server/server.js",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "devother": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot & nodemon ./server/server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot --inline --progress --colors --watch --content-base ./\" \"nodemon ./server/server.js\""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://I have replaced this for privacy on stackoverflow.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://I have replaced this for privacy on stackoverflow"
  },
  "homepage": "https://I have replaced this for privacy on stackoverflow",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.4.1",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.21"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in data whenever you are accessing it. Either initialize it with an array that has an element or check if the array is empty before rendering.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    data: [{
        name: "tmp"
    }]
});

// or with optional chaining

return (
    <div> <h1>List of Cards</h1>
       {data?.data?.length && (
            <div>{data.data[0].name}</div>
       )}
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if "data" is valid first before rendering

```
<div>{data && data.data[0].name}</div>
```